# How to use an an asynchronous readFile call that resolves to a value in an if condition (Express)

Tags: node.js, express

I'm creating an Express endpoint where I validate whether the username/password is in my db (json file)

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    let userData = req.body;
    if (validateEmailAndPassword(userData.username, userData.password) {
        res.send(userData);
    } else {
        res.status(401).send({ error: "Username/Password combination is incorrect." });
    }
})

const validateEmailAndPassword = (username, password) => {
    let validCreds = false;
    fs.readFile('db/users.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (data) {
            const stream = JSON.parse(data);
            const usersFound = stream.filter(info => {
            if (info.username === username && info.password ===password) { return true; }
            })
        if (usersFound.length >= 1) { validCreds = true; }
        return validCreds;

        } else {
            throw Error(err);
        }
    })
}
```

'validateEmailAndPassword(userData.username, userData.password)' in line 3 of the first block of code returns 'undefined' in the if condition because it's asynchronous.

What's the best way to resolve 'validateEmailAndPassword(userData.username, userData.password)' synchronously so that I get a value of true/false without using readFileSync?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on @Estradiaz answer...

It sounds like you want to use it syncronously, so you could just make it synchronous instead of having it asyncronous and await it:

readFile -> readFileSync

```
const validateEmailAndPassword = (username, password) => {
    let validCreds = false;
    var data = fs.readFileSync('db/users.json', 'utf8');
    if (data) {
        const stream = JSON.parse(data);
        const usersFound = stream.filter(info => {
            if (info.username === username && info.password === password)
                return true;
        });

        if (usersFound.length >= 1)
            validCreds = true;

        return validCreds;

    } else {
        throw Error(err);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use `async` `await` and `promises`

```
router.post('/login', async(req, res) => {
    let userData = req.body;
    if (await validateEmailAndPassword(userData.username, userData.password)) {
        res.send(userData);
    } else {
        res.status(401).send({ error: "Username/Password combination is incorrect." });
    }
})

const validateEmailAndPassword = (username, password) => {
    let validCreds = false;
    return new Promise(resolve => {
    fs.readFile('db/users.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (data) {
            const stream = JSON.parse(data);
            const usersFound = stream.filter(info => {
            if (info.username === username && info.password ===password) { return true; }
            })
        if (usersFound.length >= 1) { validCreds = true; }
        resolve(validCreds);
        return validCreds;

        } else {
            throw Error(err);

        }
    })
    })
}
```

tada